# How can I work with JSON to get Bureau of Labor Statistics data into Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Highcharts has some good examples on how to incorporate JSON file into charts, but their examples are with [pretty simple JSON files](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json).

Here's what I want to do.

Take this example from JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/xhz7oujw/):

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{           
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
});
```

and replace the data with this file (http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/LASST410000000000003) from the BLS:

```
{
  "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
  "responseTime": 16,
  "message": [

  ],
  "Results": [
{
  "series": [
    {
      "seriesID": "LAUCN040010000000005",
      "data": [
        {
          "year": "2013",
          "period": "M11",
          "periodName": "November",
          "value": "16393",
          "footnotes": [
            {
              "code": "P",
              "text": "Preliminary."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "year": "2013",
          "period": "M10",
          "periodName": "October",
          "value": "16536",
          "footnotes": [
            {
             ...
             }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I simply want to replace the y axis data with the "year" and "period", and replace the values with "value." My issue is that I don't know how to get these in a nice format, for example, [something like this](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json).

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseData(json) {
    series = json.Results[0].series[0];
    var newData = [], m, d;
    for (var i=0; i < series.length; i++) {
        m = series[i].periodName.substr(1); // strip out the letter "M" from the periodName
        d = new Date(series[i].year, m, 1);
        newData.push({d, series[i].value);
    }
     return newData;
}
```

This will loop through the JSON and pull out the periodName (ignoring the letter "M") to get the month number and the year.  It will combine them into a date (the `d` variable).  Then it will push this date and it's associated value into the `newData` array which is returned by the function.

To use it, just call `seriesData = parseData(rawJSON)` where `rawJSON` is the contents of the source data file you pointed to here: http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/LASST410000000000003

Then just use the `seriesData` in your HighCharts setup.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the JSON with either:

```
JSON.parse(//JSON string)
```

or

```
$.parseJSON(//JSON string)
```

Once you have the JSON object, then you just write a function to grab the data you want.

Once you have the data, you can call:

```
myChartObject.series[0].setData(//parsed Data, true);
```

If you want to constantly update the data, then you need to write a function that does an ajax call to grab and set the data using a timeout period.

Example

```
//When you create your Chart object, set the events object
myChart = new HighCharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        ...
        events: {
            load: requestData //function
        },
        ...
    }
});

function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: dataSource,
        cache: false,
    }).done(function (data) {
       // parse JSON
       // set data
    }).always(function () {
        setTimeout(requestData, 6000);
    });
}
```